# UTF-8 - can't get it to work, PHP

Tags: php, html, mysqli, character-encoding

I have a script where you create a table inside a database with the entered name. But whenever I'm using `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8">`, the table names with characters like "Å, Ä, Ö" (Swedish) is not being created. But then when I remove the `<meta>` the problem disappears but then my html content can't display those characters.
I hope someone understands this. Grateful for ANY answear. Thanks!

This is my current code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['add'])){
//variables
$school = strip_tags(strtolower($_POST['addSchool']));
//connect
$connect = new mysqli("localhost","root","","skolide");
$connect->set_charset('utf8');
$query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ".$school."(
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`text` TEXT NOT NULL,
`ip` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ( id )
)";
$result = $connect->query($query);


}

?>
```

Comment: Keep your table names ASCII, it makes your life a whole lot easier

Comment: The site is Swedish. It would be a quite big problem. Thanks.

Comment: Why should it be such a big problem? Table names should be hidden from users, so should only be used by developers... yu're already encountering problems for precisely this reason; but what does your table create actually look like? Are you properly validating the table names that your users enter? Are you enclosing table names in backticks for example?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifiers.html

Comment: So you aren't enclosing the table name in backticks: if you have to use non-ASCII table names, read the rules in the MySQL manual link that I posted

Comment: And don't assume that `strtolower()` will work with UTF-8 either.... use [mb_strtolower()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php)... though if you're allowing users to create non-ASCII table names, why insist on forcing them to lower case?

Comment: Do you mean like so: ``".$school."``? (backticks)

Comment: I assume that I am talking to a coding geni ;) I am pretty new to PHP. Thank you so much for taking your time.

Comment: No! backticks (`) like you're using for the column names - see my answer..... but I really advise against doing this; it's unnecessary, bad design, and you're creating a rod for your own back when you're clearly not experienced enough for it yet

Comment: Okay, I probably going to edit code, like you suggest. Thank you.

Comment: I was putting backticks there but stackoverflow is treating it like code input.

Answer (score 2):

1. DO NOT create DB tables from user input.
2. DO NOT create DB table names from arbitrary charset.
3. Do not use any meta surrogate to substitute any real HTTP header.

**Create all the tables yourself, with installation script, once. From the names already written in the dump you provided.**

Comment: Because the way you are doing it is wrong. Table name is a subject of a program, not user interface. Please, please, please, fetch yourself at least one book before trying to employ yourself as a programmer